# How to find out which html tag based on the id in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a jsp page with more form fields.The form fields are based on some conditions.That is, If the data is present then it shows within the `<label>` tag. Else a `<input>` tag will shows.(If the data is there then it want to show, otherwise want to input the data). Id of `<label>` and `<input>` fields are same. I want to find out the tab by the specific id. Then only I have to validate that.

jsp

```
 <%if(data!=null&&!data.equals("")){ %>
     <label id="data"><%=data%></label>
 <%}else{ %>
     <input type="text" style="width:95%;" name="data" id="data" value="" >
 <%} %>
```

Java script

```
 function validate(){
     if()
         //want to find out the tab is label based on the id "data"
         //get data from label tag
         var value=document.getElementById("data").innerHTML;
     else
         //get data from input tag
         var value=document.getElementById("data").value;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check `tagName` property of element:

```js
function validate() {
   var el = document.getElementById("data");
   var str = el.tagName == "INPUT" ? el.value : el.innerHTML;
}
```

If tag is `input`, then `str` gets its `value`, else it gets `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code also

```
function validate(){
if(document.getElementById("amountRecommended").tagName=="LABEL" ) {   //for label    
var value=document.getElementById("data").innerHTML;
}else  {       
var value=document.getElementById("data").value;//for input
}
}
```